# actionCable of Rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

In this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-chat-app-with-rails-5-actioncable-and-devise/)

I can understand almost of it.

But only one part I can't.

```
//javascripts/channels/rooms.coffee

App.global_chat = App.cable.subscriptions.create {
    channel: "ChatRoomsChannel"
    chat_room_id: ''
  },
  connected: ->
    # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
    # Data received

  send_message: (message, chat_room_id) ->
    @perform 'send_message', message: message, chat_room_id: chat_room_id
```

the method `send_message` with the content `@perform 'send_message', message: message, chat_room_id: chat_room_id`. Show that as Javascript:

```
function(message){
 return this.perform('speak', {
        message: message
      });
}
```

My problem is where is the function of perform?
I tried to modify the `@perform` to `@performs` and the function would't work.

Comment: "I tried to modify the @perform to @performs" - why? What was your hypothesis about what will happen?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I just want to know where is perform function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined in rails. Here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/faa9a29fbbacc95e86c0ab3056a4443aa94e5530/actioncable/app/assets/javascripts/action_cable/subscription.coffee#L58-L60

```
class ActionCable.Subscription
  constructor: (@consumer, params = {}, mixin) ->
    @identifier = JSON.stringify(params)
    extend(this, mixin)

  # Perform a channel action with the optional data passed as an attribute
  perform: (action, data = {}) ->
    data.action = action
    @send(data)
```

The object you get from `App.cable.subscriptions.create`, it will have this method/function.